# Cannot assign value of type 'Int' to type 'Int?'

Tags: swift

I am trying to find out the `count` of first and last name value exit in an array of `a` and return a result as`[String: Int]` a count with the same key.

I am getting error on this line   `newResult[arg.key] = counts` . **Cannot assign value of type 'Int' to type 'Int?**

```
  func abbreviation(a:[String], b: [String : String]) ->[String : Int] {
        let dict = b.reduce([String : Int]()){ (result, arg) in
            var newResult = result
            let counts = a.reduce(0) { (newcount, value) -> Int in
                let count = newcount + (value.components(separatedBy:arg.value).count - 1)
                return count
            }
            return newResult[arg.key] = counts
        }
        return dict
    }
```

//result

```
let dict = abbreviation(a:["This is chandan kumar and chandan kumar and new chandan","check chandan kumar","non ame"], b:["first":"chandan","last":"kumar"])
```

Comment: What is the expected result returned by `abbreviation`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is so confusing, and you may need to be accustomed to take it as `Swift cannot infer some types in this context`.

With this line:

```
return newResult[arg.key] = counts
```

Do you know what is returned with this `return`-statement? It's a `Void`, also known as an empty tuple. (`Void` is the result type of assignment statement in Swift.) You might have expected `newResult` would be the result of the closure, but that sort of things would not happen unless you explicitly write `return newResult`.

Try changing the line in to the following:

```
newResult[arg.key] = counts
return newResult
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to return the result of an assignment expression:

```
return newResult[arg.key] = counts
```

or maybe you are trying to assign to the result of a return statement? This line doesn't make sense which way you look at it. You should separate the two things you are doing:

```
newResult[arg.key] = counts
return newResult
```

It seems like in this situation, you should use the other overload of the `reduce` method - `reduce(into:_:)`.

The `reduce` method you are currently using requires you to return a new value every time, but you are just adding a KVP to a dictionary i.e. modifying an existing value. This means that you are creating lots of copies of dictionaries. This is a good sign that `reduce(into:_:)` might be a better fit.

```
func abbreviation(a:[String], b: [String : String]) ->[String : Int] {
    // notice the parameter label "into:"
    let dict = b.reduce(into: [String : Int]()){ (result, arg) in
        let counts = a.reduce(0) { (newcount, value) -> Int in
            let count = newcount + (value.components(separatedBy:arg.value).count - 1)
            return count
        }
        result[arg.key] = counts // with reduce(into:_:), you don't return anything, just modify the first argument
    }
    return dict
}
```